# Enlarging views within android?

Tags: android, user-interface, view

Is there a way to use the visual editor in eclipse ADT or xml to enlarge the sizes of views. I cannot seem to drag enlarge or code enlarge views like switches, buttons... etc.

Thanks for the tips guys. Sorry for the novice question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to define your view dimensions.

Also you should read the docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html